# use string.at() to find a space in a string c++

Tags: c++, string, find, whitespace, space

I'm trying to find a space at a certain spot in a string but I'm having a lot more trouble than I anticipated.

I have tried a lot of ways but none worked and the one that made more sense was

```
if (isspace(string.at(3)))
{
    spacePresent = true;
}
```

Let's say my string is 123 56, I want it to return true, if it's something like 123456, it would be false. I've been on this for hours and now I have to go sleep, hopefully I can work it out after a good night sleep...

The way I tried above gives me an out_of_range error.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at

Comment: Good Night...... By the way, **what's your question?**

Comment: What is the length of your string when you get the error? And are you certain about that?

Comment: You mean [something like this](http://ideone.com/ZVKA1m) ? Though I surmise `string`, a poorly named variable if ever there was one, doesn't hold what you think it does. Post your complete code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.size()>=4 && isspace(string.at(3)))
```

That exception means what is says on the tin. 3 is out of range for the string.

NB 1: `isspace(.)` identifies various space characters (like tab, etc.). I assume that's what you want and not just plain old `==' '`.

NB 2: `string` isn't a great choice of identifier given it is also the name of the class. May cause you (but not the compiler) confusion.

Comment: Well, the naming conflict will only cause confusion and maybe a weird bug. But namespaces should take care of compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

So all the ways I've tried before would've probably worked had I known that std::cin >> input; doesn't work with spaces.

About the string name, it was something else in my editor and it's my first time posting here so I changed it thinking it'd be simpler but oh well..

I'm now using this to get my number string input and it works well with what WhozCraig posted in the comments :

```
std::getline(std::cin, x);
```

Comment: You didn't even mention how you were capturing the string. A good lesson in posting a MCVE